# Python: Convert dictionary with arrays as values to table

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a file that partially looks like this:

```
{'PLGLB1': array([0, 2, 2]), 'IL20RA': array([2, 0, 0]), 'MORC1': array([2, 0, 0])}...
```

and I want the output to be in a table-like form:

```
PLGLB1 0 2 2
IL20RA 2 0 0
MORC1 2 0 0
```

without any indentation or brackets. How can I do it?

I tried with:

```
for i in dict:
    print("{}\t{}".format(i,dict[i]))
```

(it is the continuation of a big script) but I get this output:

```
BAIAP3  [0 2 2]
CALCA   [0 2 2]
MYT1    [2 0 0]
```

Comment: What have you tried? A `for` loop and a `print` would go a long way in solving your problem.

Comment: How did that file even come to be? That's a _horrible_ data serialization format. You should probably fix that upstream instead of trying to parse that thing. (Just so we're clear, `{'PLGLB1': array([0, 2, 2]), 'IL20RA': ...` is __text__ in a file, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a dictionary, and the fact that you're trying to put it into a dataframe like structure, I would consider using `pandas`. It's fast, and you can get your desired frame in one short line (assuming your dictionary is called `my_dict`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
```

which returns:

```
        0  1  2
PLGLB1  0  2  2
IL20RA  2  0  0
MORC1   2  0  0
```

I'm unsure of your final goal, but it seems like you want this to end up being outputted as a text file (correct me if I'm wrong), in which case you can just do this:

```
df.to_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', header=False)
```

Which will make a text file called `filname.txt` looking like this:

```
PLGLB1 0 2 2
IL20RA 2 0 0
MORC1 2 0 0
```

**Note**: If the outputted `.txt` is your only goal, and you don't want to work with the dataframe in Python, you can even chain the whole thing without saving the frame as `df`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index').to_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'PLGLB1': [0, 2, 2], 'IL20RA': [2, 0, 0], 'MORC1': [2, 0, 0]}

for key in dictionary:
    print(key, *dictionary[key])
```

Sounds like this is what you're looking for. The star in the print statement removes the brackets from the lists and separates the elements with a space.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your input is a long string, as shown in the question.
No standard parser for this format likely exists. [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to the rescue.

```
import re

entry_rx = re.compile(r"'(\w+)': array\(\[(\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\]\)")

def print_group_per_line(input_string):
    for match in entry_rx.finditer(crazy_text):
        print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(*match.groups()))
```

Testing it:

```
>>> crazy_text = "{'PLGLB1': array([0, 2, 2]), 'IL20RA': array([2, 0, 0]), 'MORC1': array([2, 0, 0])}"
>>> print_group_per_line(crazy_text)
PLGLB1 0 2 2
IL20RA 2 0 0
MORC1 2 0 0
```